# Git pull hangs on SMB shared repository

Tags: macos, git, bitbucket, macports, msysgit

When I run git pull, I get this:

```
edson$ GIT_TRACE=1 git pull -v
trace: exec: 'git-pull' '-v'
trace: run_command: 'git-pull' '-v'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--git-dir'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--is-bare-repository'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--show-toplevel'
trace: built-in: git 'ls-files' '-u'
trace: built-in: git 'symbolic-ref' '-q' 'HEAD'
trace: built-in: git 'config' 'branch.master.rebase'
trace: built-in: git 'config' 'pull.rebase'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '-q' '--verify' 'HEAD'
trace: built-in: git 'fetch' '-v' '--update-head-ok'
trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'git@bitbucket.org' 'git-upload-pack '\''xxxltd/xxxltd.git'\'''
trace: run_command: 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all' '--quiet'
trace: run_command: 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all'
trace: exec: 'git' 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all'
From bitbucket.org:xxxltd/xxx
 = [up to date]      master     -> origin/master
 = [up to date]      blah -> origin/blah
trace: run_command: 'gc' '--auto'
trace: exec: 'git' 'gc' '--auto'
trace: built-in: git 'gc' '--auto'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '-q' '--verify' 'HEAD'
trace: built-in: git 'fmt-merge-msg'
```

But then it just hangs there.

The (bitbucket) repository is inside a windows 7 vmware machine. The repository is then shared via SMB to the host machine (mac osx). I'm running git pull (macports) on the host.

If I run git pull (msysgit) inside the vm, it works fine.

Any clue?

Comment: I am seeing the exact same thing.  It wasn't happening consistently until I upgraded to Mavericks.  I think it might be a permissions issue with SMB but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Now that you mention, it does happen more frequently since I upgraded to Mavericks too. Also, when I run git pull inside the vm, sometimes the repository becomes unusable for the host (until I delete .git/index and do git reset)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Git source, there seems to be a infinite loop in [Git's fmt-merge-msg function](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/fmt-merge-msg.c#L531) when the repo sits in a SMB share while being accessed from Mavericks. The only way I've been able to fix this is by doing doing a process that doesn't involve automatic merging.

`git pull` is essentially a `git fetch && git merge` all in one command. If you try and do a `git fetch` into your current branch when there have been changes, you may run into an issue where the `git fetch` fails.

The way that I've fixed this issue is to fetch the remote branch into a temporary local branch and them merge that temp branch into your working branch. See the following which details trying to fetch the latest changes from your `origin/master` into your current working branch `master`.

1. Fetch the latest changes from `origin master` into a local branch called `master_merge_tmp`. `git fetch [<remote loc>] [<remote branch>]:[<local branch>]` allows you to fetch the latest changes without invoking `fmt_merge_msg` automatically and you can target a different local destination branch:

   ```
   git fetch origin master:master_merge_tmp
   ```
2. Merge the `master_merge_tmp` branch into `master`:

   ```
   git merge master_merge_tmp
   ```
3. Perform some cleanup by deleting the remote branch `mater_merge_tmp`:

   ```
   git branch -D master_merge_tmp
   ```

Alternatively you could create a helper function to automate the steps above. You can place this in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`:

```
# Workaround for fmt-merge-msg issue on Mavericks w/SMB repo
# gfm [<remote>] [<remote branch>]
function _git-fetch-merge() {
  local remote="$1"
  local branch="$2"
  local tmp_branch="${2}_merge_tmp"
  git fetch $remote $branch:$tmp_branch
  git merge $tmp_branch
  git branch -D $tmp_branch
}
alias gfm="_git-fetch-merge"
```

Now from the terminal you can do the following:

```
_git-fetch-merge origin master
```

Or you can use the alias:

```
gfm origin master
```

If you are working with a remote upstream branch:

```
gfm upstream master
```

Comment: Brilliant answer!! I couldn't find any clues anywhere online. Thank you so much!

Comment: Your welcome! This one was a tough one to beat and forcing SMB1 over SMB2 was still not fixing the issue. If can ever get some time I'll have to submit a bug report to Git about this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Apple switched to SMB2 with Mavericks and it's not working so well for quite a few people. As an alternative, here's a more permanent fix you can apply instead of the temporary one of `cifs://`:

**To force all connections to be SMB1:**

Open A terminal window
paste in the following line followed by the return key (should be all on one line):

```
echo "[default]" >> ~/Library/Preferences/nsmb.conf; echo "smb_neg=smb1_only" >> ~/Library/Preferences/nsmb.conf
```

**What the command does:**

Creates a file called nsmb.conf  in your  home directory at the path **~/Library/Preferences/nsmb.conf**.
Adds directives to force SMB connections to use the SMB1 protocol.  This is slower but stable.

**How to remove the workaround:**

Open a terminal window
paste in the following at the prompt and then hit the return button:

```
rm ~/Library/Preferences/nsmb.conf
```

**Notes:** ( [source](http://cammodude.blogspot.com/) )

> Its a good idea to restart your mac before trying to connect to your
>   storage again. This will clear any hung SMB processes from previous
>   attempts to connect to your storage before implementing this
>   workaround.

---

> EDIT: Commenter replied "it wasn't helpful" — not the best choice of words, but you get the idea.

Comment: @psyrendust, if you have any other logs, or additional info, let us know.

Comment: To make things more clear. I've tried all of the following and will still run into the issue where doing any type of git action which requires `fmt-merge-msg` to run will prevent the git action from completing: Mavericks SMB2, SMB1 via `smb_neg=smb1_only` as answered by @lll, mounting via cifs, using automount (config'd auto_smb with fstype=cifs, fstype=smbfs, fstype=smb, cifs://, smb://), installed smb3 using homebrew, tried a freshly cloned repo [github](http://bit.ly/Leetp5). Nothing works. Oddly enough connecting through `prlufs` mounted to `/Volumes/C` works...

Comment: You can see my [Win 7 VM info here](http://psyrendust.github.io/git-pull-hangs-on-smb-shared-repository/), [My Mac SMB setup here](https://gist.github.com/psyrendust/8590635#file-mac-smb-config-sh), and my [Mac System Info here](https://gist.github.com/psyrendust/8590635#file-mac-system-info-txt). This has been duplicated on 2 brand new 2014 15" Retina MBP's, 1 mid 2013 15" Retina MBP, and 1 late 2013 15" Retina MBP all Running Mavericks 10.9.1. We have 1 mid 2013 15" Retina MBP that is running Mountain Lion 10.8.5 with the same environment setup that has no issues.

Comment: We didn't experience this issue until we had upgraded to Mavericks. We were also experiencing issues where running certain Grunt tasks (ones doing regex replacements) would cause `NUL` chars to be inserted into files, or a random `NUL` file would appear in the Mac file system. We are also experiencing grunt task generated files via while connected via smb could created locked files in our Win 7 VM where the files would have no user or group that could be recognized by either the host OS or VM OS & only a reboot of the VM would allow the files to be deleted (I suspect an issue w/watch tasks)

Comment: Another update. I tried out a couple of other VM's Ubuntu (worked fine using SMB1 & SMB2), Windows 8 (did not work on SMB1, SMB2, SMB3), and I tried out connecting to another Mac running Mavericks (all worked fine using SMB1, SMB2, and AFP).

Comment: I Pulled down the latest source for Git, put down some trace statements and compiled. I found an infinite loop happening in fmt-merge-msg.c in the function find_merge_parents() where line [560](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/fmt-merge-msg.c#L560) never gets called because the `if` statement on line [550](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/fmt-merge-msg.c#L550) always evaluates to true because `len == 0` and is always less than `43`. This causes the `continue` on line [554](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/fmt-merge-msg.c#L554) to always get called.

Answer (score 0):

Mavericks has known issues with the SMB protocol. Try mounting the repo as `cifs://vm.ip` instead of `smb://vm.ip` [(source)](http://www.tuaw.com/2013/10/27/did-mavericks-kill-your-network-drive-access-heres-a-fix/).

Comment: I get "There was a problem connecting to the server "xxxxx"